# Unwanted frame around markers in legend

Tags: legending

I am plotting the following data    `data = {{{0, 32.5}}, {{2, 23.7}, {5,22.35}, {10,20.13}}, {{2, 29.75}, {5, 25.4}, {10,25.5}}, {{5, 29.9}, {10, 28.75}}, {{5,30.75}, {10,26.65}}};` with the instruction

```
ListPlot[data,PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {15, 35}},PlotRangePadding -> {1, 0}, PlotMarkers ->Thread[{ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[All, 1]] /.Thickness[_] :> AbsoluteThickness[4], .07}],PlotStyle -> ColorData[40, "ColorList"], PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8"},LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20},LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Right],FrameLabel -> {"parameter", "property"}, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None},GridLines -> {Automatic,Automatic},ImageSize -> 600]
```

as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I get some unwanted frames around the triangle up and down symbols in the legend (for s4 and s5). How to get rid of them?
Also, I would like to shift the legend upwards. How to do it?

I am using Mathematica 10.0.2
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = RandomInteger[40, {5, 10}];
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {15, 35}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {1, 0}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Thread[{ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[All, 1]] /. 
      Thickness[_] :> AbsoluteThickness[4], .07}], 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[40, "ColorList"], 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8"},
      LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
       FontSize -> 20}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Right], 
  FrameLabel -> {"parameter", "property"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}, 
  GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

You can post-process to remove the unwanted rectangle around the markers:

```
lp /. {Opacity[_], Rectangle[__]}:> {}
```

[image]

Comment: Ho to shift the legend upwards or downwards?

Comment: @Luigi, you can replace `Right` with `{After, Top}` or with `{After, Bottom}` in the last argument of `Placed`. To get a finer control of placement you can  replace `Right` with `ImageScaled[{1, .3}]` and play with the numbers to get the position you like.